# Pandas: subtracting one cell value from column values

Tags: python, pandas

Asking this question because my new cells are populated with NaN's and I could not find the answer I needed on here.

Say I have the following dataframe (this is a virtual subset of a larger and spliced dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array([['onset', 100], ['NaN', 200], ['NaN', 350], ['NaN', 400]]), columns=['Event', 'Time'])
```

so:

```
      Event  Time
   0  onset  100
   1  NaN    200
   2  NaN    350
   3  NaN    400
```

And I want to create a column with relative timestamps like:

```
      Event  Time  reltime
   0  onset  100   0
   1  NaN    200   100
   2  NaN    350   250
   3  NaN    400   300
```

How would I go about it? I figured I'd locate the Time at the onset with `loc` and subtract that value from the column like so:

```
onsettime = df.loc[df['Event']=='onset', 'Time']
df['onsetlatency'] = df['Time']-onsettime
```

For info:

```
[In] print onsettime
[Out] 0    100
Name: Time, dtype: int64
```

However, this only works for the first row, even though both values are int64. (as below)

```
      Event  Time  reltime
   0  onset  100   0.0
   1  NaN    200   NaN
   2  NaN    350   NaN
   3  NaN    400   NaN
```

What's the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If always exist value `onset` seelct first value by indexing:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'].astype(int)

onsettime = df.loc[df['Event']=='onset', 'Time'].values[0]
df['onsetlatency'] = df['Time'] - onsettime

print (df)
   Event  Time  onsetlatency
0  onset   100             0
1    NaN   200           100
2    NaN   350           250
3    NaN   400           300
```

More general solution - if value `onset` not exist get `0`:

```
onsettime = df.loc[df['Event']=='onset', 'Time']
df['onsetlatency'] = df['Time'] - next(iter(onsettime), 0)
```

Comment: i don't know why we have to convert to `int`. in `pd.Dataframe()` we are taking `int`. But without converting its gives `str` error, can you please tell?

Comment: @Nihal - It is problem with `DataFrame` constructor, here is use `np.array`, so all values are casted to string arrays (because  `NaN` string).

Comment: @Nihal - Check it by `print (np.array([['onset', 100], ['NaN', 200], ['NaN', 350], ['NaN', 400]]))`

Comment: @Nihal one can refrain from such a problem by using a dictionary while creating. For example this `df = pd.DataFrame({'Event': ['onset', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN'], 'Time': [100, 200, 350, 400]})` doesn't require conversion into an `int` type.

Comment: @jezrael can you help this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865312/how-to-merge-csv-files-with-different-headers-but-same-data-on-condition

Comment: @panda - Sorry, not understand second df :(

Comment: @jezrael what do you mean by second df? can you please comment on the question link

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onsettime = df.loc[df['Event']=='onset', 'Time']
df['onsetlatency'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda x: float(x) - float(onsettime[0]))
```