# merge consecutive matching rows

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge all consecutive rows by matching all 'X' fields and concatenating the 'Y' field.

Below is sample data -

```
[Y  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5
A   NaN -3810   TRUE    None    None
B   NaN -3810   TRUE    None    None
C   NaN -3810   TRUE    None    None
D   NaN -3810   None    None    None
E   NaN -3810   None    None    None
F   NaN -3810   None    None    None
G   NaN -3810   None    None    None
H   NaN -3810   TRUE    None    None
I   NaN  2540   TRUE    None    None
J   NaN  2540   None    True    None]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCMAk.png)

Expected output -

```
[A B C  NaN -3810   TRUE    None    None
D E F G NaN -3810   None    None    None
H       NaN -3810   TRUE    None    None
I       NaN  2540   TRUE    None    None
J       NaN  2540   None    True    None]
```

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJPts.png)

As stated, if any of the X fields changes in the consecutive row, they shouldn't concatenate.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `itertools.groupby`

Good to remember that `itertools.groupby` handles constructiveness for us.

```
from itertools import groupby

Y = df.Y
X = df.filter(like='X').T  # df.drop('Y', 1).T
K = lambda x: (*X[x].fillna('NA'),)

tups = [
    (' '.join(Y.loc[V]), *X[V[0]])
    for _, [*V] in groupby(Y.index, key=K)
]

pd.DataFrame(tups, columns=df.columns)

         Y  X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
0    A B C NaN -3810  TRUE  None  None
1  D E F G NaN -3810  None  None  None
2        H NaN -3810  TRUE  None  None
3        I NaN  2540  TRUE  None  None
4        J NaN  2540  None  True  None
```

Comment: This is great Sir

Comment: Thx @Wen-Ben (-:

Comment: @piRSquared - Thanks. This worked. One question, is there a way to pass "all columns except Y" kind of notation for df.filter? My original variable names aren't X1...Xn so I included all of them using df.filter(items=['X1', 'X2'...]) .

Comment: You could also do `X = df.drop('Y', 1).T`

Comment: @piRSquared could you please help the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865312/how-to-merge-csv-files-with-different-headers-but-same-data-on-condition

Answer (score 3):

A little bit tricky , using `shift` create the groupkey , then `agg`

```
df.fillna('NaN',inplace=True) # notice here NaN always no equal to NaN, so I replace it with string 'NaN'
df.groupby((df.drop('Y',1)!=df.drop('Y',1).shift()).any(1).cumsum()).\
     agg(lambda x : ','.join(x) if x.name=='Y' else x.iloc[0])
Out[19]: 
         Y   X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
1    A,B,C  NaN -3810  TRUE  None  None
2  D,E,F,G  NaN -3810  None  None  None
3        H  NaN -3810  TRUE  None  None
```

Comment: H NaN 2540.0 True None None
I NaN 2540.0 None True None

H I NaN 2540 True NaN NaN  <- these shouldnt have grouped.

Comment: Done. Added those samples to the question. The given samples H & I are getting concatenated with the given code which shouldnt have happened.

Comment: I dont see a difference between this code and the one you originally gave apart from the back assignment. Still have the same result. H & I are getting grouped.

Answer (score 0):

```
col1=df1.iloc[:,1:].astype(str).agg("*".join,axis=1)
col2=col1.ne(col1.shift()).cumsum()
df1.groupby(col2).agg({'Y':' '.join,'X1':'first','X2':'first','X3':'first','X4':'first','X5':'first'})
```

out：

```
         Y  X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
0    A B C NaN -3810  TRUE  None  None
1  D E F G NaN -3810  None  None  None
2        H NaN -3810  TRUE  None  None
3        I NaN  2540  TRUE  None  None
4        J NaN  2540  None  True  None
```