# How to calculate the multidimensional array with broadcasting?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, broadcast

I calculated the elements by double `for` loop as follows.

```
N,l=20,10
a=np.random.rand(N,l)
b=np.random.rand(N,l)
r=np.zeros((N,N,l))

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        r[i,j]=a[i]*a[j]*(b[i]-b[j])-a[i]/a[j]
```

Question:

1. How to vectorize the array and calculate it with broadcasting?
2. I also want to set the index `i`not equals`j`, which means leave the diagonal element as zero. Can I do that also by vectorization?

Answer (score 1):

You can broadcast all of the arithmetic and remove the loop.s

```
r2 = (a[:,None]*a) * (b[:,None]-b) - (a[:,None]/a)

# Verify the correctness
np.array_equal(r, r2)
# True
```

Finally, to set diagonals to zero, either use in-place assignment

```
r2[(np.arange(N),)*2] = 0
```

Or, `numpy.fill_diagonal`, which also fills in-place.

```
np.fill_diagonal(r2, 0)
```

Comment: Thx, is there a way to keep the diagonal elements original value 0?

Comment: @kinderchen Not sure what you mean? This seems to produce the same output as your current code.

Comment: Yep, I just wonder if it's possible that it can keep the diagonal element as zero too.

Comment: @kinderchen Use `np.fill_diagonal(r2, 0)`

Comment: @coldspeed could you help the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865312/how-to-merge-csv-files-with-different-headers-but-same-data-on-condition