# obtaining indices of n max absolute values in dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

suppose i create a Pandas DataFrame as below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
x = 10*np.random.randn(5,5)
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

as an example, this can generate the below:

[image]

for each row, i am looking for a way to readily obtain the indices corresponding to the largest n (say 3) values in absolute value terms. for example, for the first row, i would expect [0,3,4]. we can assume that the results don't need to be ordered.

i tried searching for solutions similar to idxmax and argmax, but it seems these do not readily handle multiple values

Comment: Please seed your RNG before generating your dataframe. Can you update your picture and explanation for if the RNG was seeded to zero?

Comment: `argpartition` on the absolute values should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.argsort(axis=1)`

Given dataset:

```
x = 10*np.random.randn(5,5)
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
           0          1         2          3          4
0  17.640523   4.001572  9.787380  22.408932  18.675580
1  -9.772779   9.500884 -1.513572  -1.032189   4.105985
2   1.440436  14.542735  7.610377   1.216750   4.438632
3   3.336743  14.940791 -2.051583   3.130677  -8.540957
4 -25.529898   6.536186  8.644362  -7.421650  22.697546

df.abs().values.argsort(1)[:, -3:][:, ::-1]
array([[3, 4, 0],
       [0, 1, 4],
       [1, 2, 4],
       [1, 4, 0],
       [0, 4, 2]])
```

Comment: could help the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865312/how-to-merge-csv-files-with-different-headers-but-same-data-on-condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( this is not the optimal code ) :

```
idx_nmax = {}
n = 3
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    idx_nmax[index] = list(row.nlargest(n).index)
```

at the end of that you will have a dictionary with:

as Key the index of the row

and as Values ​​the index of the 'n' highest value of this row