# Dynamically Appending new string to existing one

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas

I have a dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,2,2,2], 'b':['x','y','u','w','v']})
```

It should select the values of column `b` based on value passed for column `a`.
Say I want to select all the values of column `b` for value `2` in column `a` and produce the following string

```
There are 3 values for value 2.
1. u
2. w
3. v
```

I am doing it using `for` loop as below:

```
x = df[df['a']==2]['b'].values

result = "There are {} values for 2.\n".format(len(x))
z = ""
for i, val in enumerate(x):
    temp = "{}. {}\n".format(i+1, val)
    z += temp

print(result+z)
```

Above solution is working but I'm looking for more efficeint solution.

*Context: I'm creating a chatbot response. So trying to reduce the response time*

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: `df[df.a==2].b.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: `df.loc[df['a'].eq(2),'b'].values` should be faster i guess

Comment: @anky_91 Agree! My sol keeps it as a dataframe object. That's all! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use to_string

```
x = df.loc[df.a == 2, 'b']

print('There are {} values for value 2.\n'.format(len(x)))
print(x.reset_index(drop = True).to_string())

There are 3 values for value 2.

0    u
1    w
2    v
```

Comment: This looks concise but it's actually taking more time than my solution.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar, pandas methods are more readable but usually not as efficient as vanilla Python. I personally don't see anything wrong with using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Another sol:

```
m=df.loc[df['a'].eq(2),'b']
m.index=list(range(1,len(m)+1))
print('There are {} values for value 2.\n'.format(len(x)))
print(m.to_string())

There are 3 values for value 2.

1    u
2    w
3    v
```

Comment: could you help the following question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865312/how-to-merge-csv-files-with-different-headers-but-same-data-on-condition

Comment: @panda saw that could not understand much though. :(

Comment: still were you understand?