# Converting month number to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I transform a month number (float) to datetime in pandas with a format like 2010-01-01?

```
    date
0   1.0       
1   2.0       
2   3.0       
3   4.0       
4   5.0
```

**Expected output:**

```
    date
0   2010-01-01       
1   2010-02-01      
2   2010-03-01      
3   2010-04-01       
4   2010-05-01
```

Comment: Any particular reason the year is 2010? is it something else you desire?

Comment: If you know that your year is 2010, you can append the string first. df.date = pd.to_datetime('2010-' + df.date.astype(str), format = '%Y-%m')

Comment: Thats the year I need @Chris

Comment: how can I add the day? @Vaishali

Comment: Pandas will by default assume 1 as date, else you can concatenate that as well. pd.to_datetime('2010-' + df.date.astype(str) + '-1', format = '%Y-%m')

Comment: @Vaishali Had to reformulate my question. I've tried a lot of things but isn't working

Comment: @Pepe, see the answer I just posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append year and month and convert to date time

```
pd.to_datetime('2010-' + df.date.astype(int).astype(str) + '-1', format = '%Y-%m')

0   2010-01-01
1   2010-02-01
2   2010-03-01
3   2010-04-01
4   2010-05-01
```

Comment: can you please help the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865312/how-to-merge-csv-files-with-different-headers-but-same-data-on-condition

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution can be to just add the `year` and `day` columns to the data frame, and call `pd.to_datetime(df)`:

```
df = df.assign(year=2010, day=1, month=lambda l: l.date.apply(np.int)).drop('date', axis=1)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df)

df = df.drop(['year', 'month', 'day'], axis=1)

print(df)

        date
0 2010-01-01
1 2010-02-01
2 2010-03-01
3 2010-04-01
4 2010-05-01
```

Comment: Had to reformulate my question, it's a float not a int.

Comment: @Pepe Edited answer.

Comment: @ernest_k can you please help the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54865312/how-to-merge-csv-files-with-different-headers-but-same-data-on-condition