# How to convert month number to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have followed the instructions from this thread, but have run into issues.

[Converting month number to datetime in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879143/converting-month-number-to-datetime-in-pandas)

I think it may have to do with having an additional variable in my dataframe but I am not sure. Here is my dataframe:

```
0 Month Temp
1 0     2
2 1     4
3 2     3
```

What I want is:

```
0 Month    Temp
1 1990-01  2
2 1990-02  4
3 1990-03  3
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
df= pd.to_datetime('1990-' + df.Month.astype(int).astype(str) + '-1', format = '%Y-%m')
```

And I get this error:

ValueError: time data 1990-0-1 doesn't match format specified

Comment: what month is `0`?

Comment: It should be January of 1990

Comment: then you should do `df.Month.add(1).astype(str)`

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, we can manually create your datetime object then format it as your expected output:

```
m = np.where(df['Month'].eq(0), 
             df['Month'].add(1), df['Month']
).astype(int).astype(str)


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(
        "1900" + "-" + pd.Series(m), format="%Y-%m"
    ).dt.strftime("%Y-%m")

print(df)

   Month  Temp     date
0      0     2  1900-01
1      1     4  1900-02
2      2     3  1900-03
```

Comment: I get this error : time data 1900-1.0 doesn't match format specified

Comment: @EliTurasky edited need to add `astype(int)`, remember as a `strftime object` you're dealing with a string not a datetime object

Comment: Now I get this error : ValueError: time data 1900-13 doesn't match format specified

Comment: Still getting this error unfortunately : ValueError: time data 1900-13 doesn't match format specified

Comment: @Eli Turasky then you have an error in your data, 13 isn't a month

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for you

```
import pandas as pd
Data = {
    'Month' : [1,2,3],
    'Temp' : [2,4,3]
}
data = pd.DataFrame(Data) 
data['Month']= pd.to_datetime('1990-' + data.Month.astype(int).astype(str) + '-1', format = '%Y-%m').dt.to_period('M')



    Month    Temp
0   1990-01   2
1   1990-02   4 
2   1990-03   3
```

If you want Month[0] means 1 then you can conditionally add this one

Comment: Get this error : ValueError: time data 1990-0-1 doesn't match format specified

Comment: Just restart kernel and then run all

Comment: Maybe package problem just check conda update conda

Comment: If you will get this same error just remove "conda remove --force pandas" then reinstall it "conda install -c anaconda pandas"

Answer (score 0):

Try .dt.strftime() to show how to display the date, because datetime values are by default stored in %Y-%m-%d 00:00:00 format.

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({'month':[1,2,3]})

df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format="%m").dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

print(df)
```

You have to explicitly tell pandas to add 1 to the months as they are from range 0-11 not 1-12 in your case.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'month':[11,1,2,3,0]})
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['month']+1, format='%m').dt.strftime('1990-%m')
```

Comment: I get this error: ValueError: time data '0' does not match format '%m' (match

Comment: That's because you're having months like indices 0- Jan, 1- Feb ... Just add 1 to the series while converting to datetime